# Defining main in shared library on OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, shared-libraries, program-entry-point

I'm using xcode to write an OSX app in c/c++.

I'm linking a shared library (somelib.dylib) to the application and I'd like for the main function to reside in the shared library, not the main executable.

Is this possible?

When I try, the program crashes in the startup code.

The shared library DOES define a main function.

Also, is there a way to force xcode to show what commands it is issuing when it build a project?

Comment: what is C/C++ ? C intersect C++ ? C union C++ ?

Comment: I am writing certain parts of the app in c, other parts in c++

Answer (score 1):

Shared libraries don't work the way you want them to. Main must reside in the actual program. That said, there's nothing that stops you from simply calling a function in your library that runs the rest of the program logic.

i.e.

```
//... includes

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  return Library::Run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Max. However, I must contradict what you've said: When building an application for linux, the main function can indeed be inside a shared-library I link to the executable. I know this is true because I have done it, it just doesn't appear to work on OSX. Thanks for the help just the same.